# WebStorm code inspection to detect when an unknown prop is passed to a React Component

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, react-proptypes, code-inspection

My team really wants syntax highlighting in WebStorm when a component is called with a prop that isn't defined in that component's propTypes.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    static propTypes = {foo: PropType.string};
    ...
}

...

<MyComponent
    bar={...} // this line would be marked as a warning/error
    foo={"some string"}
/>
```

**Is it possible to create a custom code inspection to perform this? How would we go about it?**

WebStorm already offers prop name completion, and warns if a required prop is not being passed, so it seems like all of the necessary information already exists. (See the "Completing component properties" section of [React - Help | WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react.html).)

---

*Side note: obviously this wouldn't catch props passed dynamically (e.g. `<MyComponent {...someObject} />`), but we consider that an anti-pattern anyway.*

Comment: Wouldn't react with typescript be something that would meet your needs? As javascript is a dynamic language, who is to say whether or not a prop makes sense or not?

Comment: A type system like Typescript would also solve this, but we would need to translate our entire codebase to take advantage of that. We already have propTypes defined for every component.

Comment: "who is to say whether or not a prop makes sense or not? " That is the exact point of defining propTypes.

Comment: I would say that propTypes help somewhat in type safety, as making sure that all required props are passed and that they are of the expected datatype / shape (also for the optional ones in that case), however, it doesn't enforce restraints. If you want that type safety, then typescript is the way to go